# Does an AT825 fit inside the Rode Blimp?

Tags: rode, blimp, stereo, microphone

Has anybody tried it? I emailed Rode but got no response.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. I have used my AT-825 in the Rode Blimp and it worked great for recording outdoor ambience. As I recall it was a bit of a squeeze to snap into the included hoops but the mic did fit. I did remove the short through-handle mono xlr cable as it is useless with the 825. Ideally you'd run a short stereo 5-pin XLR in its place.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about the 825 but the 4025 will fit nicely and they're almost the same size. [GEARSLUTZ THREAD ABOUT IT](http://www.gearslutz.com/board/post-production-forum/505617-bp4025-field-recording.html)

Comment: This is what I found:

BP4025
186.0 mm (7.32") long, 
47.6 mm (1.87") head diameter 
21.0 mm (0.83") body diameter

8.43" (214.0 mm) long, 
2.44" (62.0 mm) head width, 
0.83" (21.0 mm) body diameter

So there kind of similar, I'm just worried about the width of the head.

Answer (score 0):

4025 even fits into a baby ball gag. among the best tips i've gotten here so far...